# Android Studio Artic Fox not initializing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Android Studio Artic Fox not initializing. How to fix this problem?

[image: Error]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Android Studio and clear the temp folder under `C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Android/sdk`.

Then reinstall Android Studio